# How to auto generate web api js for custom entity CRUD methods?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I can see that in the Angular 5 UI Project we have a file `\src\app\shared\service-proxies.ts`

it seems to be an auto generated file:

```
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NSwag toolchain v11.12.9.0 (NJsonSchema v9.10.9.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)) (http://NSwag.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------
```

I need to create a new component for crud on a custom entity.
I have the menu item and routing working but i'm having trouble understanding the doco for how this file `service-proxies.ts` actually gets generated.

i can only assume it has something similar to this [link](https://blog.rsuter.com/nswag-tutorial-generate-an-angular-2-typescript-client-from-an-existing-asp-net-web-api-web-assembly/)

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: You make a DTO class and make a service inheriting from IApplicationService and define methods in this file. Are you asking this?

Comment: no, i'm in the angular web app, not the host

Comment: You should generate(replace) this file manually with the help of NSwagStudio.

Comment: i have now installed NSwagStudio - just trying to understand how it all works now...thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here is the answer:

Step 1: make sure your host is running

Step 2: in the angular project locate the nswag folder

Step 3: run the refesh.bat file

this should produce the updated file for `service-proxies.ts`

too easy...once you know! :-)

PS: if you are using angular 5 you will need

```
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v3.4.0
```

Comment: i noticed the language component does not get generated - may have to be a manual step - if you need localization

Comment: The command 'path to the nswag.exe' failed with error. Is there any solution? I compare the files between the file in above link and the file in my project. There are a couple of lines more but the others are fine.